# Editing windows Registry

Tags: windows

Hai 
Is there any way to edit the Registry of an system from another system in Lan.
That is Whether it is possible to edit registry of an client system from server

Comment: Do you want it programatically? Else this has to go to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the windows tool Regedit supports to connect to remote registry, there is obviously an API available. Look at the [RegConnectRegistry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724840%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to get more information.

Maybe you want to give us a hint to your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many ways.

You could use the registry editor and click file->connect network registry.

Or you could RDP (or VNC) into the target server and make the change.

Or do you mean programatically?

Comment: Thaks i got it but i am unable to access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE of that computer its giving me an error message why?
Is it possible by programming if possible help me
Thank u

Comment: @Chaithu: You need to give more description of what you are trying to do. If you are just trying to do it through regedit you should go an ask on superuser.com or serverfault.com instead. Make sure you include what error message you are getting. If you trying to do it in code check out Franks answer, and look at the RegConnectRegistry api function. You need to give us more detail and explain what language you are using, what exactly you are trying to do and what error you get.